# How to get Selected Row on button click of WPF Grid Control with CheckBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress, wpfdatagrid

I have a `CheckBox` unbound `Column` in `GridControl`. Now it want to get he `Selected/Checked` `Row` of `Grid` Control in `WPF` and insert these rows in another table.

`XAML`

```
<dxg:GridControl Name="grdInfill" Height="700" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
        <dxg:GridColumn AllowEditing="True" FieldName="Dummy">
            <dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox Name="chkSelect" HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=DataContext.RowData.Row.GlassType}" Checked="CheckEdit_Checked" Unchecked="CheckEdit_Unchecked" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
        </dxg:GridColumn>
    <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="GlassType" AllowEditing="False">
</dxg:GridColumn>

    <dxg:GridControl.View>
        <dxg:TableView Name="grdInfillInner"  ShowTotalSummary="True" AutoWidth="True" DetailHeaderContent="True"  ShowIndicator="False" ShowGroupPanel="False" CellValueChanging="grdInfillInner_CellValueChanging"><!--GroupRowTemplate="{StaticResource descriptionHeader}"-->
        </dxg:TableView>
    </dxg:GridControl.View>
</dxg:GridControl>
```

`Code`

```
protected void GetAllInfills()
{
    List<Infill> infillList = new List<Infill>();
    infillList=BLL.GetAllInfills();

    if (infillList != null)
    {
        grdInfill.ItemsSource = infillList;
        grdInfill.GroupBy(grdInfill.Columns["Glass.GlassType"], ColumnSortOrder.Ascending);
        grdInfill.GroupBy(grdInfill.Columns["Glass.Glass_Description"], ColumnSortOrder.Ascending);
        grdInfill.AutoExpandAllGroups = true;
    }
}
```

**How to get the Seleted Row values on Button Click!**

Comment: check [this](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q308696).

Comment: please note i want to get row only when checkbox is checked on button click..! so sorry!